# nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:22

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-config

whenever I tried to enter the code above in the Nginx config file I found this error.which is nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:22.
I tried in HTTP tag but can't solve it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5mg1.png)

Answer (score 0):

What ever config you create in `site-enabled` or `conf.d` directory, will be imported in `http` block in `nginx.conf`.

So, when you write `http` block in your config, you have sth like this:

```
http {
    http {
        server {
        }
    }
}
```

So you should not declare `http` block in your config.

Comment: Hey Amin I am a newbie and still do not get your point I share my conf file code in the image .what exact changing should I do?